# WSDL2Apex Generation Failed Element not defined for part 'result'

Tags: webservices, soap, wsdl, wsdl2apex

I'm trying to import a wsdl file into salesforce with wsdl2apex, however i'm failing with the following error:

> **Apex Generation Failed** 
>   Element not defined for part 'result'

These are my message components:

```
<wsdl:message name="GetUserDataRequestMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="userdata" element="tns:getUserData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetUserDataResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="result" type="tns:personData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SystemErrorMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="error" element="tns:systemError"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetBulkUserDataRequestMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="userdata" element="tns:getBulkUserData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetBulkUserDataResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="result" type="tns:BulkPersonData"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

I'm not that familiar with soap and wsdls, but i've been reading up on the WSDL standard and managed to understand that my problem lies somewhere in these lines

```
<wsdl:message name="GetUserDataResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="result" type="tns:personData"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

and

```
<wsdl:message name="GetBulkUserDataResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="result" type="tns:BulkPersonData"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

this is what my schema looks like:

```
<schema targetNamespace="<!-- censored -->"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="<!-- censored -->"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

        <element name="getNRN" type="tns:RNRType" />
        <element name="getUser" type="tns:UserType" />
        <element name="getSession" type="tns:SessionType" />
        <element name="systemErrorMessage" type="tns:systemErrorType" />
        <element name="getBulkUserDataRequestMessage" type="tns:BulkUserDataElement" />
        <element name="getBulkUserDataResponseMessage" type="tns:BulkPersonData" />
        <element name="getUserDataRequestMessage" type="tns:userDataElement" />
        <element name="getUserDataResponseMessage" type="tns:personData" />

        <complexType name="userDataElement">
            <sequence>
                <element name="nrn" type="string" />
                <element name="user" type="string" />
                <element name="session" type="string" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="RNRType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="nrn" type="string" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="UserType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="user" type="string" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="SessionType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="session" type="string" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="personData">
            <sequence>
                <element name="nrn" type="string" />
                <element name="language" type="string" />
                <element name="name" type="string" />
                <element name="familyname" type="string" />
                <element name="street" type="string" />
                <element name="number" type="string" />
                <element name="boxnumber" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="index" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="postalcode" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="municipalitynl" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="municipality" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="countrynl" type="string" />
                <element name="country" type="string" />
                <element name="email" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="phone" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="alliance" type="string" />
                <element name="vp" type="boolean" />
                <element name="cmdv" type="boolean" />
                <element name="vt" type="boolean" />
                <element name="omnio" type="boolean" />
                <element name="nrnentitled" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="emailentitled" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="phoneentitled" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="vtentitled" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="omnioentitled" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="systemErrorType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="error" type="string" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="BulkUserDataElement">
            <sequence>
                <element name="user" type="string" />
                <element name="session" type="string" />
                <element name="nrn" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="BulkPersonData">
            <sequence>
                <element name="singlePersonData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:SinglePersonData" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="SinglePersonData">
            <sequence>
                <element name="person" type="tns:personData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
                <element name="error" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="rnr" type="string" use="required" />
        </complexType>
    </schema>
```

As far as I could understand from the wsdl standard and documentation the problem lies in the fact that for some reason salesforce can't handle the `type="tns:personData"` or the `type="tns:BulkPersonData"` in the wsdl message part.

**Is there something I can do to circumvent salesforce and get the apex classes generated?** Perhaps can I change my wsdl file manually to have those issues fixed?

Comment: This project [An alternative to Salesforces Wsdl2Apex...](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/03/an-alternative-to-salesforces-wsdl2apex.html?m=1) is trying to address some of the problems. Worth a try.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a copy of the complete WSDL? Change any URLs etc... If you need to. Try changing wsdl:part names from result to narrow down which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I tried changing the part names, but without success, I can send you a copy of the WSDL (without endpoints) send me a DM on twitter (@pjcarly)

Comment: @PJC I've messaged you on twitter about the WSDL. When replying on StackExchange can you start the comment with at username so I get a notification :)

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem?  I am experiencing something similar

Comment: No, I got lucky, I asked the people I got the wsdl from, to regenerate it for me, and afterwards it was fixed. Never knew what the trouble here was, sorry.